# Google Earth - Color Coded elevation data

Tags: google-earth, elevation, google-earth-pro

I don't know anything about Global Information Systems.
I want to do something which should be extremely simple and extremely common sense

I have Google Earth Pro. I just want to see a color-coded elevation layer.

That's it.

You would think that that would be standard. I've searched for years on the Internet, and everyone makes such a big deal about doing stuff like this. And people have bits and pieces of things here and there, and they do all kinds of weird, complicated, useless things. And they end up doing everything else BUT THIS. And, as far as I have seen, no one actually ever produces anything like this end.

In the days before compututors, maps were made all the time with this color elevation data. You know, green at sea level and then yellow, orange, and red, as you go higher.

There should be a webpage somewhere that just says, "Click here to add a color elevation layer" to Google Earth.

Man, what's up with that?

You say well that's ArcGIS DEM 90m DVD px nTV-KML DVR 40GB blah blah blah. Get over it. No it's not that complicated. Look at all of the layers that they put in Google Earth. You have like an "Endangered Species" layer, a "Hiking Trails" layer. And you're telling me that you can't do an elevation layer?

I can't believe they give people degrees for this stuff in college. There's too many people involved in this stuff and too little results.

Comment: what country do you want?  do you mean something like this? http://www.floodmap.net/Elevation/CountryElevationMap/?ct=US

Comment: @Daniel Shevel - I'm following your instructions but I'm not sure what type of layer to add, is it vector layer or one of the other 17 layer types? Then is it the .hdr or .tif file that I upload? I keep getting an error saying unknown file type.

Answer (score 1):

Or something like this:

[image]

You have to make a colored map and export to kmz,and make map transparent.

Comment: You have to find srtm data for whole world, and make area with elevation, then export to google earth. You can use Global Mapper, or trow the QGIS export with plugin google earth. Has a lot to do about it.

Comment: That is very nice!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a great KMZ of a Global Relief Model from NOAA: https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/global/relief/ETOPO1/tiled/ice_surface/etopo1_ice_surface.kmz

You can also load these KMZ files from Space Shuttle Radar Topography Mission (SRTM) on Google Earth.

30-meter digital elevation model
http://topex.ucsd.edu/srtm30_plus/SRTM30_PLUS.kmz

15-meter digital elevation model
ftp://topex.ucsd.edu/pub/srtm15_plus/SRTM15.kmz

also have a look at this web page:
https://gisgeography.com/free-global-dem-data-sources/

there's another website which offers global relief map:
https://maps-for-free.com/

Answer (score 1):

I looked for the answer on the same question, and I found!

**1)** Download **srtm** (Geo Tiff). For example from here: https://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/srtmdata/

**2)** Install QGIS and add srtm file in QGIS as layer.

**3)** Open properties of layer: Symbology -> Render type -> singleband pseudocolor. Chose interpolation and color ramp. Set values and colors. Apply.
[image: properties]

**4)** Export layer -> save as -> use GeoTIFF format and Output mode "Rendered image", then save new file.
[image: export]

**5)** Import new geotiff file in Google Earth.
[image: result]